# What is the intersection of surfaces when the answer is not unique?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I had the question in a recent assignment that given:

> $z=x^2+y^2$ and $2x−4y−z−1=0$

Find the curve of intersection (answer is not unique).

I have tried to add the first equation into the 2nd, but it only gives me a single circle.

Comment: The circle you found is (probably) the projection of the intersection into the $xy$-planep -- i.e. you found a cylinder whose intersection with either of the given curves is the actual intersection, which is a (tilted) ellipse obtained by intersecting a (tilted) plane with a (parabolic) bowl.

Comment: @Ned Yes I see this. But it seems to me this gives a unique solution? There is only one intersection, no?

Comment: What is supposedly "not unique" in this problem? Given two surfaces in $3$-space, the intersection is a unique set of points regardless of the surfaces, so "non-unique" must have some other meaning here. Maybe it means there isn't a unique canonical way to express that elliptical intersection ?

Comment: Well. The answer has to be a parametrization of the intersection, which by the writer of the assignment, is not unique. Thats what I am getting from this.

I guess that makes sense since if I use some free variable, t, for the parametrisation I could just use t-1 and it would still hold, if that's what he meant

Comment: That sounds good, parameterize the circle for $x$ and $y$ and use either given equation  for $z$ -- and of course you can transform the parameter $t$ as well as you said.